# Tkinter - Getting x,y coordinates of Label object

Tags: python, tkinter

I have defined a `Label` object as:

```
panel = Label(image_frame, image=self.img, cursor="cross")
```

Now, I'd like to do draw polygon on top of this, and I have created a function called `draw()` that binds to a canvas and will allow me to draw a polygon on top of it. So, I know my `draw()` command works.

However, I need to do this on top of the panel that I've defined as a Label. 
The biggest problem I'm having is this line in my `draw()` command

```
if event.widget.canvasx(event.x)-2 < orig_x < event.widget.canvasx(event.x)+2 and event.widget.canvasy(event.y)-2 < orig_y < event.widget.canvasy(event.y)+2 :
```

I'm producing the following error:

> AttributeError: 'Label' object has no attribute 'canvasx'

Is there an analog for `canvasx` for `Label` object?  How can I bypass this without changing `Label`? Or is changing `Label` to canvas my only option?

The only other thing I can think of is to have a transparent canvas behind the `Label`, but then `on-resize`, things get messy.

Comment: How are you able to draw on top of a label? Are you certain you can do that? The canvas documentation is pretty clear that you can't draw other canvas objects on top of embedded widgets.

Comment: That is my question. I am able to draw when I bind to a canvas. But not when I bind to the Label, hence, how can I do this.

Comment: You misunderstood my question. Even if you were able to compute the coordinate correctly (and you can), you will not be able to draw a line on a canvas which will appear on top of a label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there an analog for canvasx for Label object? How can I bypass this without changing Label? Or is changing Label to canvas my only option?

No, because there is no need. `canvasx` exists because the canvas can be scrolled in any direction, and you need to be able to convert from widget coordinates to the inner canvas coordinates.

In the case of a label, if you click at the 0,0 coordinate of a label, that will always be the upper left corner of the label, because the interior of the label cannot be scrolled.

---

Note: it is not possible to embed a label widget (or any other widget) on a canvas, and then draw on top of the label. The official canvas documentation says this about that:

> Note: due to restrictions in the ways that windows are managed, it is not possible to draw other graphical items (such as lines and images) on top of window items. A window item always obscures any graphics that overlap it, regardless of their order in the display list.

Comment: I see, so my only option is to convert to Canvas, is that right?

Comment: @Jonathan: I don't know what you're actually trying to accomplish. If you want to draw a polygon on top of some other object on a canvas, you will not be able to draw on top of an embedded widget. This is spelled out in the canonical documentation. I've included the relevant phrase from the tcl/tk documentation (tkinter is just a thin wrapper around a tcl/tk interpreter).